# PHP Get list of files from Directory (in Moodle)

Tags: php, moodle

I want to open a directory and read all the files inside and put them into an `array`, so far I have:

```
$imagesdir = $CFG->dataroot.'/1/themeimages/';
```

Which gives me the path to the directory, whats the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since from your tag list I assume you're using Moodle, you can simply use the:

```
function get_directory_list($rootdir, $excludefiles='', $descend=true, $getdirs=false, $getfiles=true)
```

The function is contained in *moodlelib.php*.

Reading from the doc:

> - Returns an array with all the
>     filenames in  * all subdirectories,
>     relative to the given rootdir.

Please refer to the official doc for more information about the optional parameters.

Functions for reading content of files are also available in *filelib.php*.

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to use [`opendir`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) + [`readdir`](http://php.net/readdir) + [`closedir`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php) *(quoting an example from the first page)* :

```
$imagesdir = $CFG->dataroot.'/1/themeimages/';
if ($handle = opendir($imagesdir)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "$file\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Another solution would be to use [the `[DirectoryIterator` class][4] ; quoting the example from][4] the `__construct` page :

```
$imagesdir = $CFG->dataroot.'/1/themeimages/';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($imagesdir);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Of course, in each case, instead of just echoing or dumping the name of the file, you'd have to put it into an array.

This would mean initializing the array before the loop :

```
$list_files = array();
```

And, inside the loop, use something like one of those two lines, depending on which solution you choose :

```
$list_files[] = $file;
$list_files[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
```

Comment: Moodle offers a library function for this. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the built in function [scandir](http://www.php.net/scandir):

> Returns an array of files and directories from the directory .

So you would use it like this:

```
$array = scandir($imagesdir);
```

Of course you can use DirectoryIterator too, but this is much simplier.

You can also strip dot files:

```
$array = array_diff(scandir($imagesdir), array('.', '..'));
```

Comment: +1.  glob() is also an option, albeit more feature rich, and probably less performant http://php.net/glob

Answer (score 1):

For a more OO approach use the DirectoryIterator class.

```
$images = array();
$imagesdir = $CFG->dataroot.'/1/themeimages/';
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($imagesdir) as $file) {
   if($file->isDot()) continue;
   $images[] = $file;
}
```

Comment: Please be mindful when assigning a DirectoryIterator's "current" value to an array like that. When you come around to doing anything with the $images array, all of its items will be the same DirectoryIterator pointing to beyond the last element (and thus entirely useless).  This is expected (though unfortunate) behaviour.  Thankfully, there is a quick fix: be sure to "clone" the $file when assigning to the array.

Answer (score 1):

here's the shortest solution if you also need a filter later on:

```
$imagesdir = $CFG->dataroot.'/1/themeimages/*.*';
foreach (glob($imagesdir) as $file)
  array_push($files,$file);
```

php automatically excludes `.` and `..`

you can also specify your own mask if you don't need ALL files, as shown in above `*.*`
php also automatically creates the `$files` array for you.

the last line can also be:

```
$files[]=$file;
```